# Can't update my ubuntu kernel

Tags: apt, kernel, ssh, vps

after I updated my ubuntu to 18.0.4 （Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i686)）。
and then I want to update my kernel but after I updated I am checking by typing

```
uname -a
```

I got this:

```
3.13.0-24-generic
```

I do the update again and I got this:

```
linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0.163.152).
```

here is the message:

```
root@nordenbox:~# apt-get upgrade linux-image-generic 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
  linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0.163.152).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly  installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
root@nordenbox:~# uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

I am confused. I am new to Linux and do these jobs on my VPS via SSH.
and the CPU of my SVR is the 32-bit CPU.

```
root@nordenbox:~# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-91-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-163-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-163-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
done
```

Comment: That kernel is installed, but it would appear you are not actually running it. You did not mention you rebooted. If after rebooting the old kernel remains in effect, you may need to load the Grub menu to select a different kernel, although an update normally should put you on the updated version after reboot.

Comment: I have reboot several times but the old kernel is still there.

Comment: I am not an expert in using the Grub menu....ok,I will study it for a while, have any instructions?

Comment: Include the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` and `sudo grub-mkconfig | grep -E 'submenu |menuentry' in your question (use "edit")

Comment: SO I am studying for the Oh  My God Linux......OK,thank you ,I will do it by myself!!!